# Jython Type Error - Maximo automation script

Tags: python, jython, maximo

I'm using the below script to see if 'ttype' is changed so I can reset the value of 'tclass'

```
if ttype != None & ttype != '':
  tclass=None
```

However I'm receiving the following error when triggering the script in the application:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'NoneType' and 'unicode' in <script> at line number 1
```

I'm new to python/jython so any input would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&` is the `bitwise and` operator in python. You should be using `and` like -

```
if ttype != None and ttype != '':
```